# Apple ID for employees having no credit card

Tags: macos, apple-id

I would like to create Apple ID on my employee's desktop. She has no credit card, I can't create Apple ID without card, having no apple id she cannot update her desktop. Is there any workaround of that?

Comment: Are you doing this for one, ten or 100 employees. The workarounds vary according to scale.

Comment: actually for a few.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Head over to iTunes and select a free app. It will ask for an account. Create a new account. For payment select None and voila.

[Methods to create an Apple id without any Credit Cards](http://www.osxiosexpert.com/create-an-apple-id-without-credit-card/)

Comment: The only problem is that if you already tried to create a new account starting not from a free app you will never see NONE payment option.

Comment: You will never see the NONE option, regardless of what type of account it is.

Answer (score 6):

Apple IDs can be created with the None payment method providing you are attempting to do something that doesn't require payment. For example, you can create an Apple ID without a payment method by going to the iTunes Store and purchasing any free app. You will be prompted to create an Apple ID and can select None as the payment method.

For more information, see:

- [Create an iTunes Store, App Store, or iBooks Store account without a credit card or other payment method](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2534)

Comment: I tried that, but there is no option NONE in the payment selection.

Comment: @Luman Have you tried it with the iTunes Store?

Comment: I really don't remember _how_, but I'm pretty much sure you can do that - I've personally created my account at work without having a Credit Card.

Comment: You only get the NONE option if you're creating a new Apple ID account during the process of purchasing a free app. If the Apple ID already exists (but hasn't been used in the App Store yet), it'll require a credit card even for a free app. No, I don't know why this is...

Answer (score 0):

The "iTunes Store" workaround George Garside suggested should work, anyway the solution I eded up using for my little sister's account was providing any credit card and then removing it right after the account was created.